# PHP Imap_open with etodb class works on one server but not another

Tags: php, imap, pop3

I am using a fairly straightforward php class emailtodb to import emails to a mysql database.  Everything works perfectly as hoped when I use it to check email accounts on the local server.  The issue is I took the connection script and put it on another server and now it cant connect.  To summarize hopefully what im trying to say:

```
server1.com -accessing-> myemail@server1.com = works perfect
server2.com -accessing-> myemail@server1.com = Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream
```

This is the code im using to connect to the server

```
$mysql_pconnect = mysql_pconnect($cfg["db_host"], $cfg["db_user"], $cfg["db_pass"]);
if(!$mysql_pconnect){echo "Connection Failed"; exit; }
$db = mysql_select_db($cfg["db_name"], $mysql_pconnect);
if(!$db){echo"DB Select Failed"; exit;}

$edb = new EMAIL_TO_DB();
$edb->connect('mail.MYSERVER.com', '/pop3:110/notls', $email, $pass);
$edb->do_action();
```

which actually goes to this function to actually connect (I believe)

```
function connect($host, $port, $login, $pass){

$this->IMAP_host = $host;
$this->IMAP_login = $login;

$this->link = imap_open("{". $host . $port."}INBOX", $login, $pass);
if($this->link) {
$this->status = 'Connected';
} else {
$this->error[] = imap_last_error();
$this->status = 'Not connected';
}
}
```

Finally I would say there is one major difference between the two servers, the new server has an SSL where the first does not so the new mail connection is going from HTTPS to HTTP but I dont know if that would have anything to do with it.

Comment: can you telnet from your server onto that connection, looks like a firewall issue to me, also check apache error log as it may have more info

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with this script just this evening.  Have you tried something like this?  (assuming you're switching from POP3 to IMAP with SSL)

$edb->connect('mail.server.com:993', '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert', 'myname@server.com', 'password');

I discovered that my PHP environment didn't have PHP complied with IMAP-SSL (--with-imap-ssl in phpinfo() ), so that was causing some early problems for me too.